# Select MAX and MIN from multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, unpivot

I can get the `MAX()` and `MIN()` from multiple columns in the same table with this:

```
Select
    max(Maximo) as Maximo,
    min(Minimo) as Minimo
From(
    SELECT
        MAX(COLUMN1) AS Maximo,
        MIN(COLUMN2) AS Minimo
    FROM TABLE1
    WHERE
        COND1= 'A' and
        COND2= 'X'
    UNION
    SELECT
        MAX(COLUMN3) AS Maximo,
        MIN(COLUMN4) AS Minimo
    FROM TABLE1
    WHERE
        COND1= 'A' and
        COND2= 'X'
    UNION
    SELECT
        MAX(COLUMN5) AS Maximo,
        MIN(COLUMN6) AS Minimo
    FROM TABLE1
    WHERE
        COND1= 'A' and
        COND2= 'X'
    UNION
    SELECT
        MAX(COLUMN7) AS Maximo,
        MIN(COLUMN8) AS Minimo
    FROM TABLE1
    WHERE
        COND1= 'A' and
        COND2= 'X'
) x
```

But this looks ugly. So I am trying to use `UNPIVOT`:

```
SELECT
    MIN (v) AS MinValue,
    MAX (v) AS MaxValue
FROM
    TABLE1 UNPIVOT (
        v FOR nValue IN (
            COLUMN1,
            COLUMN2,
            COLUMN3,
            COLUMN4,
            COLUMN5,
            COLUMN6,
            COLUMN7,
            COLUMN8
        )
    ) AS U
```

And I am receiving the following error:

```
[Err] 42000 - [SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FOR'.
```

What it should be? Thanks.

Comment: Your query worked fine: Check this [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d44da/1)

Comment: Thanks for your time @TechGirl. yeah, I tested with dates (my case) and it still working (http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/18acc/1), but in my app it gives an error. Well, gonna do more tests. Thanks

Comment: Is it too late to redesign your table?  Normalizing it would eliminate your problem.

Comment: @DMason, the table is normalized. I just want to get one specific information. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you can easily write this using `CROSS APPLY` with a `VALUES` to get the final result:

```
SELECT Maximo = max(maxVal), 
  Minimo = min(minVal)
FROM table1 t
CROSS APPLY
(
  VALUES
    (COLUMN1, COLUMN2),
    (COLUMN3, COLUMN4),
    (COLUMN5, COLUMN6),
    (COLUMN7, COLUMN8)
) c (maxVal, minVal)
WHERE t.COND1= 'A'
  AND t.COND2= 'X';
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/48698/3).  This unpivots the pairs of columns and then you can just grab the `max`/`min` of each column.